# Creating a shared library for both C and C++

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

Say I want to have a small library with some common functionality for TCP sockets. Now for C++ code I want to create classes such as `TCPClient`, `TCPServer`, etc. but for C code I want to have just functions and structs.

Is it a common/recommended practice to combine those in the same shared library?

Comment: I think this is mostly opinion based and depends on your use case. There are multiple ways to go about it. But to me it sounds like you want two libraries in one, which seems like double the work. Personally I would just write the library in c and use it in my c++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have problem linking C with a C++ library.

Generate a C library (only functions and structs). Then you can either link it directly within C code, or write a C++ wrapper which declares the wanted Classes and calls C function, wrapped in an `extern "C" {}` statement.