# How to cast volatile typedef struct to non-volatile typedef struct as argument of the function

Tags: c, casting, volatile

I'm writing a C library for STM32 and ran into a problem.

I have typedef struct:

```c
typedef struct foo {
    // some struct elements
} foo;
```

Volatile variable with `foo` type:

```c
volatile foo bar;
```

And function with `foo`-typed argument:

```c
int foobar(foo* baz) {
    // some operations with baz
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to call `foobar(&bar);`, I get an error: `error: invalid conversion from ‘volatile foo*’ to ‘foo*’ [-fpermissive]`

Will it work if I cast `volatile foo*` to `foo*` ( `foobar((foo*)&bar);`)?

I tried to cast `volatile foo*` to `foo*` but I don't know if it will work without bugs.

Comment: Why not accept a `volatile foo *baz`? Accessing it through a non-volatile pointer would work as if it wasn't `volatile` (in addition to being UB, I believe), which is probably undesired, otherwise it wouldn't be `volatile` in the first place?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Because `foo` type is not always used as volatile.

Comment: Then I would make a `template` to accept both volatile and normal objects.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you mean `int foobar(volatile foo* baz) {...}; foo bar // non-volatile; foobar(&bar)` will work?

Comment: I didn't suggest this, I suggested a template. This option compiles, but probably does something undesirable too, you don't want to pay the cost of `volatile` access for non-volatile objects. You understand what `volatile` does, right?

Comment: There is no such programming language C/C++. You either develop a library with a C interface, or a C++ interface.

Comment: @273K It's possible to make cross-language both C and C++ library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691799/creating-a-shared-library-for-both-c-and-c.

Comment: Why do you defile `bar` as `volatile` ?  Do you really mean to change its contents asynchronously ?

Comment: If you make it's cross-language, then it's a subset of C. C++ is partially compatible with C, but C is not compatible with C++. And your link: **Generate a C library (only functions and structs).** Where is C++ or C/C++ there?

Comment: @chqrlie Because `bar` in my code can be changed in interrupts. It's STM32 code.

Comment: @t1m013y: Then every function accessing it should be aware that the contents can change asynchronously, hence the argument must be declared as `volatile foo* baz`.

Comment: @273K I mean "or" under "/" in "C/C++". C **or** C++

Comment: @chqrlie I can write an addition to my library for volatile structs, is it a good idea?

Comment: Not tagging both C and C++ is customary. You either can use C++ features or you're limited to C. If you're limited to C, tag C, otherwise tag C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only cast. If you need to cast this way it means that your code has a issue.

If you want to use a function which does not take a `volatile` parameter with a `volatile` object it means that this object needs to be treated as not ***side effects prone**. Your function does not have to assume that something not visible to the compiler can change it and apply optimizations which are not possible for `volatile` objects. The most important is that all accesses to the `volatile` object have to be applied to its permanent storage place.

If you have this problem then:

1. You overuse the `volatile` keyword and your `volatile` object does not have to be `volatile` (as you want to use it as non `volatile`). You should rethink your program data types.
2. You can declare the function as taking `volatile` - but it will prevent many possible optimizations.
3. You can have different functions handling `volatile` and non `volatile` data.

> Will it work if I cast volatile foo* to foo* ( foobar((foo*)&bar);)?

No. It will only silence the warnings but it can be very dangerous.

```
struct  x
{
    bool dangerous;
    float data;
};

int dangerous(struct x *ptr)
{
    if(!ptr -> dangerous)
    {
        /* do something */
        if(!ptr -> dangerous) never_call_if_dangerous_is_true();
    }
}

int dangerous_volatile(volatile struct x *ptr)
{
    if(!ptr -> dangerous)
    {
        /* do something */
        if(!ptr -> dangerous) never_call_if_dangerous_is_true();
    }
}
```

and resulting code:

```
dangerous:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi], 0
        jne     .L2
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     never_call_if_dangerous_is_true
.L2:
        ret
dangerous_volatile:
        mov     al, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        test    al, al
        jne     .L5
        mov     al, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        test    al, al
        jne     .L5
        jmp     never_call_if_dangerous_is_true
.L5:
        ret
```

in non volatile version skips the second check. If something (signal, interrupt) changes the `dangerous` member it will call the function - killing someone for example

Comment: It is almost never needed if you use the `volatile` correctly

Comment: Please explain me what exactly is dangerous and `never_call_if_dangerous_is_true()`?

Comment: Does "dangerous" mean that structure is now being used elsewhere (e.g. interrupt)?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE the tag C++ was removed after I created my answer.

You can solve this with a template function, the std::enable_it_t is an extra (SFINAE) check to avoid accepting anything other than a foo_t. Note I use refences not pointers since I expect the input to be a valid instance (with pointers you always have to do the extra nullptr check)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

/*typedef*/ struct foo_t  // <== typedef is "C" syntax, not needed
{
};

// any form of foo_t is ok (with or without const, volatile or reference)
template<typename type_t>
constexpr bool is_foo_t()
{
    return std::is_same_v<foo_t,std::remove_cvref_t<type_t>>;
}

template<typename type_t>
auto foobar(const type_t& foo) -> std::enable_if_t<is_foo_t<type_t>(),int>
{
    // reusable code here 
    // just a demo to show both arguments are accepted
    if constexpr(std::is_volatile_v<type_t>)
    {
        std::cout << "Called with volatile foo_t\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Called with non-volatile foo_t\n";
    }

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    volatile foo_t volatile_foo;
    foobar(volatile_foo);

    foo_t foo;
    foobar(foo);
}
```

Comment: I write in C to save compatibility with both C and C++. There is no templates in C.

Comment: @t1m013y See, this is why we don't like both C and C++ tags on the same question.

Comment: Yup C++ tag was removed while I was creating this answer. I will leave it here for now. At least it goes to show how different C++ and C actually are ;)

Comment: @t1m013y " There is no templates in C. " True, yet there is generic that can solve the same issue here.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Do you mean overloads?

Comment: @t1m013y Something like that, yet C does not have _overloads_.